# Is there an interactive coding platform for learning quantum computing (like DataCamp, but for quantum computing)?

Tags: resource-request

Is there an interactive coding platform for learning quantum computing (like DataCamp, but for quantum computing)?

With DataCamp, after each new concept, it gives you a window with incomplete code for you to complete and then run.  If the result is correct, you move forward.

Is there something like this for quantum computing?